# Area of triangle and uncertainty estimation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Heron's formula states that if a plane triangle has sides $a,b{\text{ and }}c$, then its area is given by $A = \sqrt {s(s - a)(s - b)(s - c)} $, where $s = \frac{1}{2} \cdot (a + b + c)$ is half the circumference of the triangle. This can also be expressed as $$A(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \sqrt {2({a^2}{b^2} + {b^2}{c^2} + {c^2}{a^2}) - ({a^4} + {b^4} + {c^4})}. $$

The sides of a triangle were measured to be  $10.0 \pm 0.1{\text{ m}}{\text{,}}\,\,\,17.0 \pm 0.3{\text{ m}}{\text{,}}\,\,\,{\text{21}}{\text{.0}} \pm {\text{0}}{\text{.4 m}}$. Use differentials to calculate an approximate  upper limit for the uncertainty in the approximation $A \approx 84.0{\text{ }}{{\text{m}}^2}$ due to the uncertainties in the measurements of the side lengths $a,b$ and $c$.

**My attempt:**

$$\begin{gathered}
  A = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt {2({a^2}{b^2} + {b^2}{c^2} + {c^2}{a^2}) - ({a^4} + {b^4} + {c^4})} ;\,\,\,\,\,\partial A = \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial a}} \cdot \partial a + \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial b}} \cdot \partial b + \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial c}} \cdot \partial c \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial a}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{a{b^2} + a{c^2} - {a^3}}}{{\sqrt {2({a^2}{b^2} + {b^2}{c^2} + {c^2}{a^2}) - ({a^4} + {b^4} + {c^4})} }} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{a \cdot ({b^2} + {c^2} - {a^2})}}{{\sqrt {(b + c - a)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(a + b + c)} }} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial a}}(10,17,21) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{10 \cdot ({{17}^2} + {{21}^2} - {{10}^2})}}{{\sqrt {(17 + 21 - 10)(10 + 17 - 21)(10 - 17 + 21)(10 + 17 + 21)} }} = \frac{{75}}{8} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial b}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{{a^2}b + b{c^2} - {b^3}}}{{\sqrt {2({a^2}{b^2} + {b^2}{c^2} + {c^2}{a^2}) - ({a^4} + {b^4} + {c^4})} }} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{b \cdot ({a^2} + {c^2} - {b^2})}}{{\sqrt {(b + c - a)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(a + b + c)} }} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial b}}(10,17,21) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{17 \cdot ({{10}^2} + {{21}^2} - {{17}^2})}}{{\sqrt {(17 + 21 - 10)(10 + 17 - 21)(10 - 17 + 21)(10 + 17 + 21)} }} = \frac{{51}}{8} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial c}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{{b^2}c + {a^2}c - {c^3}}}{{\sqrt {2({a^2}{b^2} + {b^2}{c^2} + {c^2}{a^2}) - ({a^4} + {b^4} + {c^4})} }} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{c \cdot ({a^2} + {b^2} - {c^2})}}{{\sqrt {(b + c - a)(a + b - c)(a - b + c)(a + b + c)} }} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\partial A}}{{\partial c}}(10,17,21) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{21 \cdot ({{10}^2} + {{17}^2} - {{21}^2})}}{{\sqrt {(17 + 21 - 10)(10 + 17 - 21)(10 - 17 + 21)(10 + 17 + 21)} }} =  - \frac{{13}}{8} \hfill \\
  \partial A = \frac{{75}}{8} \cdot ( \pm 0.1) + \frac{{51}}{8} \cdot ( \pm 0.3) - \frac{{13}}{8} \cdot ( \pm 0.4) =  \pm 2.2\,{{\text{m}}^2} \hfill \\
\end{gathered} $$

$$\left| {\frac{{\partial A}}{A}} \right| = \left| {\frac{{ \pm 2.2\,{{\text{m}}^2}}}{{84\,{{\text{m}}^2}}}} \right| \le \frac{{11}}{{420}} \approx 2.62\% $$

**Remark:**

What is meant by the phrase "approximate upper limit for the uncertainty in the approximation of area"? 1) Propagated error in calculating the area? 2) Relative error? 3) Relative error in percentage? The prof. used the phrase that is not commonly used. Hence I asked this question here to see how would people interpret this phrase. I have solved this problem but not sure if I did it right.

Comment: I thought "circumference" was not right, but Google told me otherwise, apologies for the unnecessary edit.

Comment: How can we help you ?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: "circumference" can be used for any closed curve, but "perimeter" is generally used for non-curvy shapes.

Comment: What is meant by the phrase "approximate upper limit for the uncertainty in the approximation of area"? 1) Propagated error in calculating the area? 2) Relative error? 3) Relative error in percentage? The prof. used the phrase that is not commonly used. Hence i asked this question here to see how would people interpret this phrase. I have solve this problem but not sure if i did it right.

Comment: You have that $A(a+h_1,b+h_2,c+h_3)=A(a,b,c)+A_1(a,b,c)h_1+A_2(a,b,c)h_2+A_3(a,b,c)h_3\\+o(\|h_1,h_2,h_3\|)$. Therefore I suppose $A(10,17,21)=84.0$. Then we can estimate the error by computing $|A(a+h_1,b+h_2,c+h_3)-A(a,b,c)=|A_1(a,b,c)h_1+A_2(a,b,c)h_2+A_3(a,b,c)h_3|$. Here $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are the derivatives of $A$ with respect to $a,b,c$ respectively.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I see. Nice to know, the Italian for "circumference" only means the contour of the circle.

Comment: "What is meant by the phrase "approximate upper limit for the uncertainty in the approximation of area"? The prof. used the phrase that is not commonly used. Hence i asked this question here to see how would people interpret this phrase." I'm gonna go off the board and say *ask your professor.*

Comment: @Jon good idea, i probly should :)